# Oracle/SQL - return parent and child records

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a question reg how to display both parent and child: 
Here is my eg:
T1 is the parent of T2.

```
ID     create datetime(mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss)
1      17-Apr-2016
2      18-Apr-2016
3      13-Apr-2016
4      15-Apr-2016
5      20-Apr-2016
6      19-Apr-2016

ID(FK) seq      create datetime(mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss)
1      6546       20-Apr-2016 
1      5457       19-Apr-2016 
1      4245       18-Apr-2016
1      0
2      5567       19-Apr-2016 
2      0
3      2034       15-Apr-2016 
3      1987       14-Apr-2016 
3      1902       14-Apr-2016 
3      1249       13-Apr-2016 
3      0
4      2209       15-Apr-2016 
4      2456       16-Apr-2016 
4      3578       17-Apr-2016 
4      3467       17-Apr-2016 
4      4645       18-Apr-2016 
4      5357       19-Apr-2016 
4      0
5      0
6      0
```

T2 is the child of T1, A and B are text values I want to display based on my condition, this is not coming from the db. My condition is:

- If Id has no create time in T2/Seq =0, list ID as 'A'. e.g: 5,6 would
  be A
- If Id has valid seq/create time in T2: 
      . then, get the max of createtime in T2
- List both rows - T1 as 'A' and T2 as 'B'

Ideally my output would be:

```
Id   createtime   Type
 1   17-Apr-2016   A
 1   20-Apr-2016   B
 2   18-Apr-2016   A
 2   19-Apr-2016   B
 3   13-Apr-2016   A
 3   15-Apr-2016   B
 4   15-Apr-2016   A
 4   15-Apr-2016   B
 5   20-Apr-2016   A
 6   19-Apr-2016   A
```

edit: i also have to add a date/time filter 
T1.createdatetime between to_date (01-Apr-2016) and to_date (30-Apr-2016)
or
T2.createdatetime between to_date (01-Apr-2016) and to_date (30-Apr-2016)

Comment: The addition is probably NOT what you want; records created on 30-Apr will NOT be selected if they have a time component different from 00:00:00, because to_date(30-Apr-2016) with no time shown means 00:00:00. I show a different arrangement in my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think just a union should do it:

```
WITH T1 as(
select 1 ID,      '17-Apr-2016' as crte from dual union all
select 2 ID,      '18-Apr-2016' as crte from dual union all
select 3 ID,      '13-Apr-2016' as crte from dual union all
select 4 ID,      '15-Apr-2016' as crte from dual union all
select 5 ID,      '20-Apr-2016' as crte from dual union all
select 6 ID,      '19-Apr-2016' as crte from dual
)
,
T2 as(
select 1 ID,     6546 SEQ,      '20-Apr-2016' as crte from dual union all
select 1 ID,     5457 SEQ,      '19-Apr-2016' as crte from dual union all
select 1 ID,     4245 SEQ,      '18-Apr-2016' as crte from dual union all
select 1 ID,     0 SEQ,         NULL as crte from dual union all
select 2 ID,     5567 SEQ,      '19-Apr-2016' as crte from dual union all
select 2 ID,     0 SEQ,         NULL as crte from dual union all
select 3 ID,     2034 SEQ,      '15-Apr-2016' as crte from dual union all
select 3 ID,     1987 SEQ,      '14-Apr-2016' as crte from dual union all
select 3 ID,     1902 SEQ,      '14-Apr-2016' as crte from dual union all
select 3 ID,     1249 SEQ,      '13-Apr-2016' as crte from dual union all
select 3 ID,     0 SEQ,         NULL as crte from dual union all
select 4 ID,     2209 SEQ,      '15-Apr-2016' as crte from dual union all
select 4 ID,     2456 SEQ,      '16-Apr-2016' as crte from dual union all
select 4 ID,     3578 SEQ,      '17-Apr-2016' as crte from dual union all
select 4 ID,     3467 SEQ,      '17-Apr-2016' as crte from dual union all
select 4 ID,     4645 SEQ,      '18-Apr-2016' as crte from dual union all
select 4 ID,     5357 SEQ,      '19-Apr-2016' as crte from dual union all
select 4 ID,     0 SEQ,         NULL as crte from dual union all
select 5 ID,     0 SEQ,         NULL as crte from dual union all
select 6 ID,     0 SEQ,         NULL as crte from dual
)

select ID, crte, 'A' Type from T1 where crte between to_date('01-Apr-2016') and to_date('30-Apr-2016')
union 
select ID, max(crte), 'B' Type from T2 where seq <> 0 and crte between to_date('01-Apr-2016') and to_date('30-Apr-2016')  group by ID;
```

OUTPUT:

```
        ID CRTE        TYPE
---------- ----------- ----
         1 17-Apr-2016 A    
         1 20-Apr-2016 B    
         2 18-Apr-2016 A    
         2 19-Apr-2016 B    
         3 13-Apr-2016 A    
         3 15-Apr-2016 B    
         4 15-Apr-2016 A    
         4 19-Apr-2016 B    
         5 20-Apr-2016 A    
         6 19-Apr-2016 A
```

Comment: This may not work if the ID does not have a row with SEQ=0 in T2; your query will return the create_date from T1 regardless. (Perhaps this is what the OP really wants - or perhaps ALL ID's have a row with SEQ=0 in T1, but that's not what the OP described in the original question.) The added conditions will **not** select records created on 30-Apr-2016 with a time different from 00:00:00.

Comment: @mathguy yea the desc was a little vague but I just based it on the ideal ouput OP provided.  I think hes also got the wrong max date for ID 4 in his output though.  But one of these solutions should cover it for him

Answer (score 0):

Something like this...  Note that I changed the input data so that it covers all possible combinations (I think).

```
with t1 (id, create_datetime) as 
         ( select 1, date '2016-04-17' from dual union all
           select 2, date '2016-04-18' from dual union all
           select 3, date '2016-04-10' from dual
         ),
     t2 (id, seq, create_datetime) as
         (
           select 1, 6546, date '2016-04-20' from dual union all
           select 1, 5457, date '2016-04-19' from dual union all
           select 1, 4245, date '2016-04-18' from dual union all
           select 1, 0   , null              from dual union all
           select 2, 5567, date '2016-04-19' from dual union all
           select 2, 4003, date '2016-04-21' from dual union all
           select 3, 0   , null              from dual
         )
select t1.id, t1.create_datetime, 'A' as type
   from t1 join t2 on t1.id = t2.id 
   where t2.seq = 0
   and t1.create_datetime >= date '2016-04-01'
   and t1.create_datetime <  date '2016-05-01'
union all
select id, max(create_datetime), 'B'
   from t2
   where create_datetime >= date '2016-04-01'
   and   create_datetime <  date '2016-05-01'
   group by id
order by id, type;
```

Output (with the data in t1 and t2 defined in the WITH clause):

```
        ID CREATE_DATE TYPE
---------- ----------- ----
         1 17-Apr-2016 A
         1 20-Apr-2016 B
         2 21-Apr-2016 B
         3 10-Apr-2016 A
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without a union and using only a single table scan on each table:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE T1 ( ID, CRTE ) AS
select 1, DATE '2016-04-17' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 2, DATE '2016-04-18' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 3, DATE '2016-04-13' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 4, DATE '2016-04-15' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 5, DATE '2016-04-20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 6, DATE '2016-04-19' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE T2 ( ID, SEQ, CRTE ) AS
select 1, 6546, DATE '2016-04-20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 1, 5457, DATE '2016-04-19' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 1, 4245, DATE '2016-04-18' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 1, 0,    NULL              FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 2, 5567, DATE '2016-04-19' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 2, 0,    NULL              FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 3, 2034, DATE '2016-04-15' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 3, 1987, DATE '2016-04-14' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 3, 1902, DATE '2016-04-14' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 3, 1249, DATE '2016-04-13' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 3, 0,    NULL              FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 4, 2209, DATE '2016-04-15' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 4, 2456, DATE '2016-04-16' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 4, 3578, DATE '2016-04-17' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 4, 3467, DATE '2016-04-17' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 4, 4645, DATE '2016-04-18' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 4, 5357, DATE '2016-04-19' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 4, 0,    NULL              FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 5, 0,    NULL              FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 6, 0,    NULL              FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT T1.id,
       COALESCE( T2.CRTE, T1.CRTE ) AS CRTE,
       CASE SEQ WHEN 0 THEN 'A' ELSE 'B' END AS Type
FROM   T1
       INNER JOIN
       ( SELECT t.*,
                CASE SEQ WHEN 0 THEN 1
                     ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY ID
                                              ORDER BY CRTE DESC
                                              NULLS LAST )
                  END AS RN
         FROM   T2 t ) T2
       ON ( t1.ID = t2.ID AND t2.RN = 1 )
ORDER BY id, type;
```

**Output**:

```
        ID CRTE                TYPE
---------- ------------------- ----
         1 2016-04-17 00:00:00 A    
         1 2016-04-20 00:00:00 B    
         2 2016-04-18 00:00:00 A    
         2 2016-04-19 00:00:00 B    
         3 2016-04-13 00:00:00 A    
         3 2016-04-15 00:00:00 B    
         4 2016-04-15 00:00:00 A    
         4 2016-04-19 00:00:00 B    
         5 2016-04-20 00:00:00 A    
         6 2016-04-19 00:00:00 A
```

**Query 2 - With filters**:

```
SELECT T1.id,
       COALESCE( T2.create_datetime, T1.create_datetime ) AS create_datetime,
       CASE SEQ WHEN 0 THEN 'A' ELSE 'B' END AS Type
FROM   T1
       INNER JOIN
       ( SELECT T2.*,
                CASE SEQ WHEN 0 THEN 1
                     ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY ID
                                              ORDER BY create_datetime DESC
                                              NULLS LAST )
                  END AS RN
         FROM   T2
         WHERE  create_datetime IS NULL
         OR     create_datetime BETWEEN DATE '2016-04-01'AND DATE '2016-04-30'
       ) T2
       ON ( t1.ID = t2.ID AND t2.RN = 1 )
WHERE  T1.create_datetime BETWEEN DATE '2016-04-01'AND DATE '2016-04-30'
ORDER BY id, type;
```

**Output**:

```
        ID CREATE_DATETIME     TYPE
---------- ------------------- ----
         1 2016-04-17 00:00:00 A    
         1 2016-04-20 00:00:00 B    
         2 2016-04-18 00:00:00 A    
         2 2016-04-19 00:00:00 B    
         3 2016-04-13 00:00:00 A    
         3 2016-04-15 00:00:00 B    
         4 2016-04-15 00:00:00 A    
         4 2016-04-19 00:00:00 B    
         5 2016-04-20 00:00:00 A    
         6 2016-04-19 00:00:00 A
```